# Infinitely scroll to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a script that scrolls to the dead end of my twitter follower [twitter.com/following] list automatically. So far, I've achieved this with my newbie knowledge:

```
var delay=2000       
setTimeout(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){   
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
},delay)
```

The problem the scroller stops after one scroll to the bottom and it doesn't scroll further when the page height changes. Is there a way to loop it with a delay so that scroll gets executed repeatedly until it reaches the last follower.

Alternatively, is there a way to do the same by constantly tracking and dynamically updating the height of the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) instead of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

`setInterval` will fire repeatedly instead of just the one time.

This works for me:

```
setInterval(function() { window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); },
            2000);
```

Comment: How to stop it once I reach the dead bottom of the page?

Comment: Yep, clearInterval. Should be described in detail at the documentation I linked to. Glad it's working for you.

Comment: When do I need to call clearInterval() method to stop scrolling once I reach bottom?

Comment: @Ken you should compare previous value of document.body.scrollHeight with current. If it is the same than there is no new content was loaded in the bottom of the element.

Comment: Yes, this worked like a charm and keeps on scrolling down indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a request delay when scrolling you can use:

```
function scrollToBottom() {
  // onscroll is only called when scrollHeight changes
  // avoiding infinit loop
  window.onscroll = () => {
    window.scroll(0, window.scrollHeight);
  }

  window.scroll(0, window.scrollHeight);
}
```